# How to set the debug options of a deployed eclipse RCP application?

Tags: logging, eclipse-rcp

I want to enable the "Debug" option for a specific plugin of my deployed RCP application. But how can I do that? Do I have to open the jar of the bundle a manipulate the `.options`-File? Or is there a working copy somewhere in the installation folder?

[http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility%3F](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility?)
This document says the `.options`-File can found in the installation directory of the RCP-App, but there is nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug options are set using *.options* file as you already discovered. This file usually contains lines like:

```
com.example.plugin/debug=true
com.example.plugin/debug/Option1=true
```

...where the first line enables debugging for the plugin as a whole and the second line enables specific debug option.

If a plugin uses debug tracing then it is a good practice to include *.options* file when a plugin is deployed, but this is not a requirement (for example, org.eclipse.core.runtime does have it). So, if the plugin that you want to enable debugging for has the *.options* file then you can copy it to your application installation directory. If not, then you need to figure out which options are used and create it yourself.

*.options* file will only be used with `-debug` command line argument. You can also specify location of *.options* file after `-debug`.

Comment: What exactly does the `-debug` argument? Does it set all debug-attributes of all bundles to `true`? Or does it force the App to use to _.options_ from the installation directory instead of the bundle ones?

Comment: `-debug` just turns on the tracing mechanism and makes Eclipse look into the _.options_ file and enable tracing options according to that. The _.options_ files in bundles are not used at all during runtime (unless explicitly specified as a parameter), those are included with plugins only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For deployed applications, I would suggest using the tracing preference page offered by the tracing plugin (available since Juno).

As documented: "The preference page can be included in other products. It is contained in the org.eclipse.ui.trace plug-in and has no dependencies on PDE."[1]

This would allow the user to toggle tracing on or off, by component, and set the location of the output (with rotating files). Here's a link to a tutorial [2].

[1] http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fpde_whatsnew.html
[2]  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePerformance/article.html#tracing_runonatruntime