# Enable a DEBUG flag in Eclipse internal JavaBuilder

Tags: eclipse

There is a class in the Eclipse source code called JavaBuilder[1], which ​has DEBUG and SHOW_STATS flags (static boolean) that I'd like to enable to debug build issues, since they enable printing reasons for rebuild, eg:

```
if (DEBUG)
    System.out.println("JavaBuilder: Performing full build since last saved state was not found");
```

I am guessing that they can be enabled with some argument in "eclipse.ini"?

I'd like to know what the argument syntax is, and where Eclipse's stdout is logged to.

Or if one can enable them without restarting Eclipse, of course.

---

[1] org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/builder/JavaBuilder.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is set by the `org.eclipse.jdt.core/debug/builder` trace option. The `org.eclipse.jdt.core/debug` option must also be set.

You can set this option by enabling tracing in the Preferences in the 'General > Tracing' page or by using a `.options` file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8801434/2670892) question)

The `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager` class defines the trace options for the JDT code.

Comment: Ok, seems promising! Got '...Contents/MacOS/.options loaded' so far...